# Thread calling methods multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to load some files from a thread, but the thread is calling the method "loadFiles()" two times. My code is huge, so I made a similar to give the idea what I'm trying to do. When i run my code, I get this output:

> ```
> 1552457003882
> 7
> 1552457003982
> 14
> ```

First it load the 7 files that I want it to load, but almost at the same time it loads the same 7 files again. "Loader" is just a class to load files. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
     {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadFiles();
                newScreen = new Screen(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, files);
                currentScreen = newScreen;
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

public void loadFiles() {
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int nFiles = 6;
    String[] sFiles = new String[nFiles];
    sFiles[0] = "file1";
    sFiles[1] = "file2";
    sFiles[2] = "file3";
    sFiles[3] = "file4";
    sFiles[4] = "file5";
    sFiles[5] = "file6";
    Loader l;

    l = new Loader("file0");
    files.add(l);
    for (int i=0; i<nFiles; i++) {
        l = new Loader(sFiles[i]);
        files.add(l);
    }

    System.out.println(files.size());
}
```

Comment: From what I can see your code looks fine. Can it be that the function `t.start();` is called twice? Did you already debug your code? This would make it easy to find out.

Comment: t.start(); is  called just once. I tryied debug, but in debug the problem desapear.

Comment: If you only want it to be called once, why is it multi-threaded?

Comment: "currentScreen" is running foreground with another screen while thread loads the new screen in background. After it's loaded, change the foreground screen.